# I would like to use greek letters on me keyboard, can you help?

Tags: keyboard, language

First of all, great job, I love it ! 
But one tiny problem for me... How can I put a Greek keyboard on it. 
I've installed elementary OS Freya on my old "greek" computer, but I can't use the greek letters.
Please help ! 
Best regards, 
K.BARDET

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where do I find the @ symbol in freya on a mac?](http://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/4738/where-do-i-find-the-symbol-in-freya-on-a-mac)

Comment: Odd though it may seem, that question does seem relevant.

Answer (score 1):

Adding the Greek layout in the keyboard settings should be enough.